# Задать псевдоним к типу из си

Tags: c, golang

Как задать псевдоним для типа из си?  Я делаю как-то так:

```golang
type Display *_Ctype_struct__XDisplay
```

Но при компиляции получаю следующую ошибку:

```
identifier "_Ctype_struct__XDisplay" may conflict with identifiers generated by cgo
```

Проблема в том, что эта ошибка появляется и при попытке указать этот тип как результат функции.  Как это можно решить?

Comment: Это же тип, который генерирует `cgo`.  Не надо его напрямую упоминать.  У вас должно быть что-то типа `C.XDisplay`.

Comment: @Ainar-G тогда выдаёт ошибку `could not determine kind of name for C.XDisplay`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`type A B` — это не объявление
псевдонима, а создание нового типа. Объявление
псевдонима — это
`type A = B`. Если там структура,
то то, чего вы хотите, делается так:

```golang
import "C"

type Display C.struct_XDisplay
```

Из [документации](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-Go_references_to_C):

> To access a struct, union, or enum type directly, prefix it with struct_,
> union_, or enum_, as in C.struct_stat.